# Why Théoden charge out at Helm's deep?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Isn't it better to defend at the narrow door (choke point, like in Spartan 300), than to charge out and get surrounded?

The orcs could have easily pierced those horses with their spears which will throw them off to the ground and get them killed.

Comment: Embedded video is no longer available.